# Frattini subgroup of a $p$- group of order $p^4$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, p-groups

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $G$ be a finite non-abelian $p$-group of order $p^4$
with the following presentation: 
$$\langle a, b, c, d\mid a^p=b^p=c^p=d^p=1, c^d=cb, b^d=ba, [a,d]=[b,c]=[a,c]=[a,b]=1\rangle.$$

According to this presentation $b=[c,d]$ and $a=[b,d]$. Is it true that $a, b \in \Phi(G)$? 
($\Phi(G)$ denotes the Frattini subgroup of $G$).

Thanks for any comment or answer!

Comment: The Frattini subgroup of a finite $p$-group contains the derived group, so yes.

Comment: Thanks for your nice point.

Answer (score 0):

This question was dealt with in the comments by Derek Holt. 
To summarise, the answer is yes, since for a finite $p$-group $G$ we have in fact that $\Phi(G)=G^{p}[G,G]$. 
For a reference of this result see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441524/if-g-is-a-p-group-then-phig-ggp).