# Showing $\Phi(G)=G'G^p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups, frattini-subgroup

Prove  $$\Phi(G)=G'G^p,$$
where $\Phi(G)$ is the Frattini subgroup of $G$, the intersection of all maximum subgroups of $G$, $G'=[G:G]$ is the commutator subgroup of $G$, and $G^p$ is the group generated by all $p$th powers of $G$.

I don't understand why this is true.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If $G$ is a $p$-group then $\Phi(G)=G'G^p$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1441524/if-g-is-a-p-group-then-phig-ggp)

Comment: @the_fox No, not exactly. The person who posted that question understands the general idea of a proof but has some questions about explicit steps. I don't even know how to begin here

Comment: You seem to have missed out the important assumption that $G$ is a finite $p$-group. Also you have made no effort at all to solve the problem yourself, so the question is likely to get closed. It seems to me that Whacka has proved the statement in the solution to the linked question. What exactly do you not understand in that solution?